# Authorize/authenticate Laravel users and Cordova users with NodeJS server (Zoho)

Tags: node.js, laravel, authentication, authorization, zoho

I am working on a platform which uses a Laravel server to deliver Web content. This Laravel server consumes services provided by a NodeJS server. Up until now, users can create accounts and login using the built-in Laravel user authentication. Some user details are passed back to NodeJS to create Zoho accounts to enable subscriptions.

Now I need to enable users to access their accounts from a mobile device. For now the mobile app is being prototyped with Apache Cordova.

Crude model:

```
User <---> Laravel <--->
                           NodeJS + database <---> Zoho
User <---> Cordova <--->
```

How should I implement user authorization/authentication to allow users to login via either Laravel or Cordova and perform authorisation/authentication in NodeJS (or even their Zoho account via NodeJS).

I have looked at OAth2, Passport, Socialite, OpenID Connect and I am now quite confused.

I don't want to use Facebook, Google, Twitter, Git etc for user authentication/authorisation. I wish to keep it within the ecosystem of Laravel, Cordova, NodeJS (and Zoho).

Surely there is an established approach or "best practice" for this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you solve the problem, if yes please add the detail, I need to do the same kind of thing

Comment: There was no solution to this problem.

Comment: Sorry! This issue was never resolved.